# How to stop losing pencils/where to put them at school

Tags: stationery

I've noticed that I've collectively lost every single fancy mechanical pencil I own since school started.

I usually put them in the side pocket of my backpack or my pocket but for some reason they've been disappearing. I dislike using pencil cases mostly because my teachers jump into the lecture as soon as people get in the classroom and I have no time to do anything but pull out a sheet of paper and begin writing. My pocket seemed like the best place but honestly I have no idea where my pencils have gone and it's rather irritating

Does anyone else have a better place to put their pencils?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some backpacks have a pen/pencil pocket.

Or you could clip your pencil to your stack of writing paper.

Or keep the pencil in your hand when you walk to class.

The back pocket of your pants isn't a good place to store any rigid object like a pencil, because when you sit down, the pocket gets folded up and the pencil is forced out.

If you have long hair, you could use the pencil as a hair pin :)

Comment: I'd use it in my hair if I knew how, but I agree wholeheartedly about the pockets (every time I drop my phone I have a heart attack)

Comment: If you have any kind of pony tail or bun, the hair from the roots to where it is kept together should be tight enough to keep a pencil fixed in place. If it is not, use a pencil/automatic pencil with thicker ends on both ends.

Answer (score 3):

One word: lanyard.

A fine cord tied around the body of the pencil under the clip (so the pencil can be hung by the cord), with the other end attached to your clothing, a neck loop (one that can't pull tighter if it snags, please), or your backpack or notebook, and long enough not to interfere with use of the pencil.

Even if (like American college students) you won't wear a uniform, this should keep your pencil with you.

Answer (score 2):

[image]

You could insert the cap of the mechanical pencil inside the 'self-loop' of your uniform tie. I am estimating that your uniform to school has a tie too.